# How to get r_object_id by content path in Documentum

Tags: documentum

I have path 
/doc/dev/documentum/data/MMM/content_storage_01/00002710/80/00/00/d3.txt

How to get r_object_id of this content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go!

```
SELECT parent_id FROM dmr_content WHERE set_file='/doc/dev/documentum/data/MMM/content_storage_01/00002710/80/00/00/d3.txt'
```